# Error while creating table in android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to create a table named by the user, but everytime my app crashes...
I'm new in android coding so, if you have any suggestion you're welcome.

```
This is the part of maine activity:

floatingMaine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_maine);
                dialog.setTitle("Nome del formulario?");
                final TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialog);
                ImageButton imageButton=(ImageButton)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButton);
                imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        //NON FUNZIONA L'INSERISCI TAVOLA
                        mydb.insertFormulario(text.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Formulario salvato", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        ArrayList array_list=mydb.getAllFormulari();
                        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,R.layout.basic_adapter,R.id.textViewAdapter,array_list);
                        obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
```

This is my database, the problem is with insertFormulario:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FormulaeDB";

    public DBHelper(Context context){ super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public boolean insertFormulario (String formulario){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + formulario /*+ "(Formule text)"*/);
        return true;//doesn't work
    }

    public boolean deleteFormulario (String formulario){
        SQLiteDatabase db =this.getReadableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST"+formulario);
        return true;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAllFormulari(){

        ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name!='android_metadata' order by name", null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
                array_list.add( c.getString( c.getColumnIndex("name")) );
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }

        return array_list;
    }

}
```

Here is my error code:

```
06-13 16:14:36.858 2658-2658/com.example.eugenioanselmino.formulae E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                     Process: com.example.eugenioanselmino.formulae, PID: 2658
                                                                                     android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{b673f86 VFED..CL. .F...... 29,16-560,134 #7f0d008b app:id/editTextDialog}
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
                                                                                         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
                                                                                         at com.example.eugenioanselmino.formulae.DBHelper.insertFormulario(DBHelper.java:30)
                                                                                         at com.example.eugenioanselmino.formulae.MainActivity$1$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
                                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: You're right... I totally forgot it.. anyway it's my first time, pe patiet... Thank you anyway:-)

Comment: i am glad that i could help , keep it up , see u around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this code:

```
mydb.insertFormulario(text.getText().toString());
```

instead of this:

```
mydb.insertFormulario(text.toString());
```

Comment: I corrected the mistake you found, but it still not working... Any other suggestion? Thank you anyway